# HiveServer2 doesn't recognize hive.aux.jars.path

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have several jar files listed in my `hive-site.xml`.  I have a table that uses special `FileInputFormat`.

When I run hive, I can do something like: `describe my-table`. Works fine.

When I run hiveServer2 and connect from beeline.  I can see the table, but when I do `describe my-table` I get:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.file.input.format.class.name (state=42000,code=40000)
```

What do I need to do to make sure hiveserver2 has access to the jar files?

Comment: what version of hadoop and hive are you using?

Comment: Are your jar files located on local file system or HDFS ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done the three steps: [user-defined-function with HiveServer2](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-8-0/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cmmc_hive_udf.html)

Comment: Thnx Luo, It cracked my problem :)